# strftime () function in SQLlite and applying it for specific definition of the day

Tags: sql, sqlite, time, group-by, strftime

I try to use `strftime('%d',time)` function to make `Group by ()` by the day. But the problem that I would like to define each day not like the usual day (from 00:00 to 23:59) but from 5:45 to 5:45 next day.

Is it possible to do in SQLlite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the following may do what you wish :-

```
strftime('%d',time) - (strftime('%H:%M',time) < '05:45')
```

That is if the time is before 05:45 then 1 (true) is subtracted from the day when determining the GROUP BY argument and thus becomes the previous day.